# Find in dictionary by value in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have such structure in my Mongo db:

```
{'_id':'...', 
    'friends': 
        {'id1': {'name1':'value1', 'name2':'value2'},
        'id2': {'name1':'', 'name2':''},
         ...}
}
```

How can I find element(friend) in this dictionary(friends) by name1(value1)?

Comment: so you're looking for a name in a list of friends? do you have a friends collection somewhere else?

Comment: @Frederico Yes, I must choose friends filtered by name. No, only here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
db.myCollection.find({"friends.id1.name1":"Sam"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
db.dbname.find({name1:'value1'})
```

If `value1` can be in any field, you can try:

```
db.dbname.find({$or:[{name1:'value1'},{name2:'value1'}]})
```

Comment: May be I put it wrong. My full document is: {'_id':'...', 'friends': {'id1': {'name1':'value1', 'name2':'value2'}, 'id2': {'name1':'', 'name2':''},...}}. I wanna find friends by their name, id1/id2 it is their ids from another document. db.dbname.find({name1:'value1'}) match nothing.

Answer (score -2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly You can do this by:

- db.collection.find({name:'value1'});

Here is a great resource to start learning mongo and various commands from it.

[Interactive Mongo Tutorial](http://www.mongly.com/)